# Input checkbox is registering my console.log but not the rest of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

code:

```
  if ($("#emotion51 input:checkbox:checked").length < 1) {
        console.log("checked<1");
        $("#step4 button[type='submit']").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#step4 button[type='submit']").removeClass("disabled");
    }
```

This is the code I am running. I want to remove the class `"disabled"` if more than 1 checkbox is checked, the `console.log` message appears but the `addClass` doesnt work if I check 1 or more checkboxes.

I basically run a form with steps, each step has a "next step" button and I want to add this validation process to the checkboxes in order for the user to proceed to the next step, but the `addClass` isnt working to remove the "disabled" class.

am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: @4b0 thats the id of the div containing the checkboxes, not the checkbox itself

Comment: Whats missing would be an eventlistener like a on click function, it would be more helpful if you could provide the whole HTML for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your function only works as the page loads you have to have an eventListener. As I do not know how your HTML works I made an example with the little information you provided. This probably will not work on every step of your form.

```js
if ($("#emotion51 input:checkbox:checked").length < 1) {
        console.log("checked<1");
        $("#step4 button[type='submit']").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#step4 button[type='submit']").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    
    
    $('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
  
  if ($("#emotion51 input:checkbox:checked").length < 1) {
        console.log("checked<1");
        $("#step4 button[type='submit']").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#step4 button[type='submit']").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="emotion51">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div id="step4">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this fixed my problem, thank you so much! Been stuck validating this step for hours